# Don't get "\" and signs of escaping when selectin from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm escaping inputs to my db with:

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

If I input:

```
"Let's see"
```

when I select from DB I get:

```
"let\'s see"
```

How do I prevent this? I'm first writing on a form, then sending it through AJAX to a .php file and then escaping it with `mysql_real_escape_string()` and nothing else.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to insert data into the database.

Comment: Magic quotes might be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why it is not fixing it however when you select something from your database you can use `stripslashes()` to return it to it's normal state e.g.

```
$str = "Let\'s see";
stripslashes($str);
echo $str;
```

Would output:

> Let's see

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like you've got [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on, which is a fantastic way to corrupt your user's data to beyond-fixable. Horrible mis-feature introduced back in the horrible old days of PHP when they thought [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) was a good idea.

Use [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead. This won't mangle your data and won't let attackers mangle your database.